# ADF- Define dynamic triggers

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-analytics

I created a scheduled trigger which executes an ADF pipeline in our development environment.
The trigger runs at 4AM on a daily basis.

I now want to release this process into our test ADF environment but the trigger should kick of at 6AM on a daily basis.

I cant find a method of dynamically changing these values based on environment.

Has anyone come across a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing trigger settings can be achieved by using ADF utils and custom parameters definitions file, I included an example in this post:  https://www.mutazag.com/blog/code/tutorial/ADF-custom-paramaters/#changing-trigger-settings

Comment: This is the right answer, here is another question where the steps are explained in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666564/adf-pipeline-trigger-deployment-on-devops